# pass one stored procedure result into other stored procedure as parameter in Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two function called in stored procedure:

```
CALL createPost(IN value,@Outvalue);
```

Now I want to pass '@Outvalue' to other stored procedure:

```
CALL createPostMedia(@Outvalue);
```

- value is retrieved when we run SELECT @Outvalue; But @Outvalue value is  not pass to createPostMedia() in parameters

Comment: create another variable and try to set the @outvalue to it? and then pass the new variable to the next proc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a small test that can be useful:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `createPost`(
    IN `_value` VARCHAR(50),
    OUT `_out_post_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `post` (`value`) VALUES (`_value`);

  SET `_out_post_id` := LAST_INSERT_ID();
END//

CREATE PROCEDURE `createPostMedia`(
    IN `_in_post_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `postmedia` (`post_id`) VALUES (`_in_post_id`);
END//

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN
  CALL `createPost`('post_one', @`_out_post_id`);
  CALL `createPostMedia`(@`_out_post_id`);
END//

CALL `sp_test`//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7fc2/1)</kbd>